# How to add C++ style multi-line comment in algorithmic Latex

Tags: latex, comments

I am using `algorithmic` to write a pseudocode in Latex. I wish to add both single(`//`) and multiple(`/**/`) lines comment in my code.

```
\ForEach {$id$ in $ids$}
    \State $id.name \gets name\_func(id.name,VALUES)$\LONGCOMMENT{$VALUES:[VERY VERY VERY LONG COMMENT THAT SCROLLS ACROSS MANY LINES]$ }
\EndFor
```

I want the comment in `\LONGCOMMENT` to appear for the lines starting with `/*` and ending with `*/` i.e

```
for each id in ids do
  id.name <- name\_func(id.name,VALUES) /*VALUES:[VERY VERY VERY 
                                          LONG COMMENT THAT SCRO-
                                          LLS ACROSS MANY LINES]*/
end for
```

The `\LONGCOMMENT` that I am using currently is:

```
renewcommand\algorithmiccomment[1]{\hfill// \eqparbox{COMMENT}{#1}}
\newcommand\LONGCOMMENT[1]{\hfill \begin{minipage}[t]{\eqboxwidth{COMMENT}}/*#1\strut */\end{minipage}}
```

My current output is

[image: My current output is]

Comment: in your output example the statement "Set a <- b-c" is commented out by the multiline comment. In the LaTeX code it looks like it isn't. Such changes are dangerous.

Comment: @Ronald In the latex code, they are not supposed to be commented, the comment should span around both the statements...